# In YUI, is there a way to reference the tab or tabview objects from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, yui, reference

It seems like there should be, but I've looked over the API and nada. I don't see how it's done in 2.x. Currently, I store references with the elements to the [tab and tabview](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/module_tabview.html) objects via jQuery's [data method](http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data).

**The why:** When I interact with the tabs via mouseovers and clicks, I need to be able to reference the YUI tab/tabview objects' properties & methods. Since I'm using event delegation b/c I have so many tabs (tabs within tabs), I'm not directly attaching (potentially hundreds of) event listeners, and thus I don't have access to the tabs and tabviews via the `this` symbol.

There's a corresponding method for buttons ([YAHOO.widget.Button.getButton](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Button.html#method_YAHOO.widget.Button.getButton)) but not one for tabs unless I'm missing something obvious.

Additionally, it seems that if I have a tab object, there's not a reference to the tabview. Once again, I create my own reference, but I assume there should be a reference or an accessor method already.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Anyone else approaching this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place for YUI questions are the forums on yuilibrary.com.

The YUI TabView component has event delegation built-in.  Every Tab event is actually handled by the TabView that it belongs to.  Each events is routed to the appropriate Tab, and the context of the handler is set to the Tab.

This allows you to assign your listeners as you normally would:

tabview.getTab(1).on('mouseover', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML); // e.target === Tab Label Element
    console.log(this.get('label')); // this === Tab instance
});

This works for nested TabViews as well.

There is currently no binding between Tab and TabView except for the TabView's "tabs" attribute.  You can iterate this collection and compare your element to each Tab's "element" attribute if there is a use-case for knowing which TabView it belongs to.

Comment: Hi Matt, welcome to SO! I've watched/listened to a couple of your YUI talks. They're great! I'm a big fan of the YUI library. However, I think many of us find SO revolutionary compared to traditional forums. I've been to both the yuilibrary forums and #yui and have found them lacking. For ex., try searching "tabview" on the forums. 29 results over 3 pages. (What's up with the vertical spacing, too?) The first page and a half are 1 topic. I have no idea how many actual results they are. Now try filtering with "event". Frustrating. This sort of frustration drives people to seek alternatives.

Comment: As for your answer, jQuery's live docs.jquery.com/Events/live gives me one listener per type of event for the entire document. It's amazingly useful and has changed how I code my web apps. Thanks for confirming about the data binding, and once again I want to express how much I appreciate YUI.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using Firebug, using the DOM tab/DOM subpanel, and actually looking through the attributes/properties/methods on the document and/or related elements? It's usually the fastest way to see what you can access.

also worthwhile to do a for..in loop to enumerate all of the properties/methods of a returned object if you are unsure what is available and unable to get that info via firebug.

e.g.

```
var properties = "";
for (prop in obj) {
    properties += prop+"\n";
}
alert(properties);
```

This is true in most cases, not just your particular question.

**EDIT**
Having just checked the YUI examples for tabview, I see there is no property on the DOM elements for the tabs that refer to JS objects. I suppose this has been done to avoid DOM pollution, but it looks like you may have to make those reference yourself when creating the tabs/tabviews

e.g.

```
var tabView = new YAHOO.widget.TabView('demo');
document.getElementById("demo").tabView = tabView;
```

Comment: Yes, I've used firebug to inspect the DOM element(s), but I don't think YUI would add to the elements' properties/methods. Just to be clear, I have the DOM element, and I want to work back to the yui object. I can go from object to element via the API, but not vice versa. What you're suggesting would mean that yui appended new methods or properties directly to the DOM element.

Comment: see my edit. yui doesn't modify the properties of the DOM element, but *you* can. When you create the YUI tabview, add the property yourself if you need to reference it from the DOM later on

Comment: I'm aware that I can. See my question, 2nd line. I think the data method is cleaner. I'm hoping a YUI expert knows a better/cleaner way to do it via the API similar to the getButton method that I mentioned. Also while it definitely looks like there is no way to get the tab object from the tab element, I'm still uncertain why/if yui would not create a reference or accessor from the tab object to the tabview object, but it looks like that's the case.